# Saving fields values and validation errors when action points to other url than form is displayed

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Is there any non-hacky way to keep validation errors and input values in this scenario:

```
1. Go to url /users/login
2. There are 2 diffrent forms, login form and create account form
3. create account form points to /users/add
4. validation fails, redirect back to /users/login with values saved and show validation errors there.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get error of your Model from

In your controller
    $this->Model->validationErrors;

and put in in a Session flash.

http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-SessionComponent.html#_setFlash